# Часовой пояс в Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

Мне нужно вывести в ячейку часовой пояс, который сейчас установлен в настройках телефона.
И чтобы название часового пояса было записано в ячейке. Как это можно реализовать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *timezoneName = [[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] localizedName:NSTimeZoneNameStyleStandard
                         locale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ru_RU"]];
targetCell.textLabel.text = timezoneName;
```

Если хотите другой формат меняйте значение `localizedName`:

- NSTimeZoneNameStyleStandard
- NSTimeZoneNameStyleShortStandard
- NSTimeZoneNameStyleDaylightSaving
- NSTimeZoneNameStyleShortDaylightSaving
- NSTimeZoneNameStyleGeneric
- NSTimeZoneNameStyleShortGeneric

Comment: не совсем понятна запись 
targetCell.textLabel.text

и что значит .name в конце

Comment: Вам надо вывести в ячейку, я так понял речь идет о UITableViewCell. Взял для примера произвольное название `targetCell`. чтоб вывести текст в ячейке надо заполнить `textLabel.text`. `name` это свойство в `NSTimeZone`, которое вернет имя для объекта `systemTimeZone`. Например если часовой пояс 'America/New_York (EDT) offset -14400 (Daylight)', то `name` будет 'America/New_York'

Comment: большое вам спасибо, а можно вывести имя русскими буквами?
или только английскими

Comment: изменил ответ .